# After enabling the SSL Magento gives 404 error to internal pages and to css and js

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, ssl, js-css

I am having a very irritating issue after i enabled the `SSL` in my website.
I changed the Base URL (Secure) from `http` to `https` and I set `"Use Secure URLs on Storefront" to YES`. 
Then I regenerated static content via this command line -:
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

And then i cleared my cache. When i see the website it is redirecting to `https` URL but CSS/JS are not loading and some images are not showing in the Home page.
And none of the links to internal pages are working. But same URL is working with `http` smoothly.

One more thing i noticed that `https` URLs are working but when i am adding `/index.php` after the website URL. This is really strange because all `http` URL works with URL re-write then why not `https` URL. To remove `/index.php` from all URLs i am using this `.htaccess` from the starts. I am still using `.htaccess` for that purpose.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I tried every possible way which are available on the internet. But nothing helps.

Comment: Can you also explain what you have tried?

Comment: I tried by removing all the contents in generated/ var/cache var/page_cache pub/static folders after then i flushed cache. But it's not working.

Comment: Can you post your full htacess?

Answer (score 0):

Your above url rewrite change is for magento 1

For magento 2 it should be just the case of enabling in backend

Stores > Configuration > Web

- expand the Search Engine Optimization section
- set Use Web Server Rewrites to “Yes.”
- When complete, tap Save Config

Your htaccess should look like this

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/.htaccess

Also maybe set *all* base URLs as https

Other than that are you able to log into admin with secure admin config set?

Comment: Thanks Dominic, I have replaced this .htaccess with my .htaccess in root magento folder. But no changed. Still same issue. I have already "Web Server Rewrite" to Yes. I have only set the Base URL (secure) to https. not the Base URL. My admin URL is set with http so it is working fine. I just need to set https only on the front-end.

Comment: You say you `enabled SSL` you got and installed a certificate on server? https://gethttpsforfree.com/